# Abrir PDF Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pdf

Estoy tratando de mostrar un PDF con Typescript, me viene en base64 y lo decodifico para ver el array de bytes.

El PDF de se abre, pero en blanco, las páginas coinciden, pero esta todas sin contenido.

El contenido en base64 os lo dejo por aquí [PDF en Base64](https://pastebin.com/kV12KXrR)

Respecto al código que uso para hacerlo es el siguiente.

En el servicio hay una llamada a la API, que es la que me devuelve el contenido.

```
getDescargaFactura(idFacturaVenta): Observable<any> {
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: this.token
    });
    const options = {
      headers: httpHeaders
    };
    const body = { IdFactura: idFacturaVenta };
    return this.http.post<any>(this.urlApi + 'Facturas/GetFacturasPDF', body, options);
  }
```

Y en el controlado, muestro el PDF.

```
descargaFactura(datos: any) {
    this._facturasService
      .getDescargaFactura(datos.IdFacturaVentaCabecera)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.pdfFactura = this._funcionesService.decodificarToken(data);
        const newBlob = new Blob([window.atob(this.pdfFactura.PDFBase64)], {
          type: 'application/pdf'
        });

        if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
          window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
          return;
        }

        const datos = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = datos;
        link.download = 'file.pdf';
        link.click();
      });
  }
```

He hecho varias pruebas y sólo consigo mostrar el PDF sin contenido, no se si es por algún tema de codificación o por el propio Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución ha sido la siguiente:

Cambiar la respuesta en el servicio. Añadiendo el `Observable<Blob>` y el header `responseType: 'blob' as 'json'`

```
getDescargaFactura(idContratoDocumento): Observable<Blob> {
    const httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: this.token
    });
    const options = {
      headers: httpHeaders,
      responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
    };
    const body = { IdContratoDocumento: idContratoDocumento };
    return this.http.post<any>(
      this.urlApi + 'Facturas/GetFacturaPDF',
      body,
      options
    );
  }
```

Una vez modificado esto, en el componente, se ha añadido directamente la respuesta del servicio al objeto blob

```
descargaFactura(datos: any) {
    this._facturasService
      .getDescargaFactura(datos.IdContratoDocumento)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          const file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
          const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          window.open(fileURL);
        }
      );
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Ademas tienes que  añadir este import.

```
import { ResponseContentType, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

En la función que tienes en el servicio tienes que añadir el tipo de dato que quieres recoger.

```
    getDescargaFactura(idFacturaVenta): Observable<any> {
        const httpHeaders = new Headers({
            Authorization': this.token
        }); 
        const options = {
            headers: httpHeaders,
            responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
        };
        const body = { IdFactura: idFacturaVenta };
        return this.http.post<any>(this.urlApi + 'Facturas/GetFacturasPDF', body, options);
  }
```

En la función que tienes en el controlador tienes que añadir el tipo de archivo.
Ademas, he añadido unas lineas comentadas, sugiriendo que utilices la libreria saveAS.

```
    descargaFactura(datos: any) {
        this._facturasService
          .getDescargaFactura(datos.IdFacturaVentaCabecera)
          .subscribe(data => {
           this.pdfFactura = this._funcionesService.decodificarToken(data);

          var contentType = 'application/pdf';
          const newBlob = new Blob([data._body], {   type: contentType})

           if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
             window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob);
             return;
           }

           const datos = window.URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
           const link = document.createElement('a');
           link.href = datos;
           link.download = 'file.pdf';
           link.click();
    /****
    *
    * Esto sería otra opcion de descarga. Faltaría añadir una libreria y su import 
    * import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

        const file = new File([newBlob ], 'nombrearchivo.xlsx',{ type: contentType});
        saveAs(file);
    */
      });

  }
```

Comment: las respuestas sin ninguna explicacion son consideradas de baja calidad . te invito a agregar una explicacion y a realizar el [tour]

Comment: Me da error en esta variable, entiendo, que porque no está declarada. Voy a probar un poco con las indicaciones que me has dado, pero tener que poner una librería de terceros, para poder ver algo que, si no entiendo mal, es nativo de Javascript, no me parece la mejor opción. Gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: ¿en qué variable?

Comment: En esta ResponseContentType.Blob

Comment: Añade este import:                                                                            
    import { ResponseContentType, Headers } from '@angular/http';

Comment: Nada sigue dando errores, como que el options no son correctos al pasarle el ResponseCntentType.Blob